# Regex not filter by delimiters

Tags: java, regex

I want to create a regular expresion where I want match in case my number are separated by a coma. 
For example:

```
 1 OK
 1,2,3 OK
 1\n2,3 OK
 1,\n Not OK
 1,,2 Not OK
 1,\n2 Not Ok
```

So far I create this expresion

```
 \d+(([,.|\n])+\d+)*
```

If I change the last * to be at least 1 with +

```
 \d+(([,.|\n])+\d+)+
```

Then all previous scenarios works but not this one

```
  1 Not OK//And should be ok
```

I´m using matcher.find()

```
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(number);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("total number:" + matcher.group(0));;
    }
```

Any idea what I´m doing wrong in my regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^\d+(?:(?:,|\n)\d+)*$
```

Java regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\d+(?:(?:,|\\n)\\d+)*$");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gX7wY0/1)

**PS:** To match literal `\n` you will need:

```
^\d+(?:(?:,|\\n)\d+)*$
```